# React routing works on local machine but not on GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have deployed my React App on Github pages but the routes are not working on Github pages.

**Only the base URL is working**. If I navigate to any other page then I get error 404.

App.js

```
<Router>

        <nav role="navigation" id="nav_bar_hamburger">
          <div id="menuToggle">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>

            <ul id="menu">
              <a href="/covid19-tracker"><li>Worldwide</li></a>
              <a href="/india-statewise"><li>India-Statewise</li></a>
              <a href="/coming-soon"><li>Coming Soon</li></a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>



        <div className="routingContainer">

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/covid19-tracker" component={WorldwideContainer} />
            <Route path="/india-statewise" component={IndianStateWise} />
            <Route path="/coming-soon" component={temp} />
          </Switch>
          <hr />
        </div>
 </Router>
```

Does BrowserRouter works differently after deploying to Github pages? What's the ideal solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **GitHub** page tries to serve `/covid19-tracker` folder or file from the server side instead of looking for routes from your React app. Probably using `<HashRouter />` is one of the solutions. So at the end you would have a URL like  `https://<github-url>/#/covid19-tracker`.

So after the base URL's hashtag your **React Router** is handling the routes accordingly.

You could add as the following in your app instead of `<BrowserRouter />`:

```
<HashRouter>
   <App />
</HashRouter>
```

Based on the documentation - Read further here: [`<HashRouter />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter):

> A `<Router>` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. `window.location.hash`) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

As also from the documentation:

> As this technique is only intended to support legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to work with `<BrowserHistory>` instead.

But in this case you probably do not have access to make that modification.

I hope this helps!